# MySQL 'AND' clause does not operate as it should

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a search engine system. In the MySQL statement, I have concatenated first name and last name and trying to get users which matches the key letters in their first name and last name. If their `account_type = 0` and `account_ban = 0`, it will also return users with `account_Type = 1` and `account_ban = 1`. Following is my query:

```
SELECT 
 firstname, lastname
FROM users
WHERE CONCAT(firstname,lastname) LIKE '%jb%'
   OR CONCAT(firstname,lastname) LIKE '%bj%' 
  AND account_type = 0
  AND account_ban = 0;
```

I have two problem here. First one that it returns users with `account_type = 1` and `account_ban = 1` also and second problem is that if I insert a space in the name e.g. `%j b%` or `%b j%`, it will not return anything. Please help.

Comment: Use parentheses to get the order of evaluation that you want.

Comment: Using the ORDER BY function?

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what you really want in terms of the spaces, but here is one solution:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM users
WHERE (CONCAT(firstname, lastname) LIKE '%j%b%' OR
       CONCAT(firstname, lastname) LIKE '%b%j%' 
      ) AND
      account_type = 0 AND account_ban = 0;
```

This will match any character between the "b" and the "j", including no characters and a space.  You can match exactly one character with `'_'`, but that doesn't seem to be what you want.  This should do the trick:

```
WHERE (REPLACE(CONCAT(firstname, lastname), ' ', '') LIKE '%j%b%' OR
       REPLACE(CONCAT(firstname, lastname), ' ', '') LIKE '%b%j%' 
      ) AND
      account_type = 0 AND account_ban = 0;
```

Comment: would you know how to implement another Clause into it which I need to make it optional as it is not necessary that the string for that is provided every time. I want to add if string for location is given, then get users from that particular location e.g. `AND` location = 'New York', thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `parenthesis` to filter proper records.

To get `account_type = 1 and account_ban = 1` you need add that condition in `where` clause. Try this.

```
SELECT firstname,
       lastname
FROM   users
WHERE  ( Concat(firstname, lastname) LIKE '%jb%'
          OR Concat(firstname, lastname) LIKE '%bj%' )
       AND ( ( account_type = 0
               AND account_ban = 0 )
              OR ( account_type = 1
                   AND account_ban = 1 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `AND` will evaluate before `OR` (thats a matematically problem) you have to make parenthesis around the `OR` statement:

```
SELECT 
 firstname
 , lastname
FROM users
WHERE 
( CONCAT(firstname,lastname) 
LIKE '%jb%'
OR
 CONCAT(firstname,lastname)
LIKE '%bj%' 
)AND
 account_type = 0
AND
 account_ban = 0
;
```

Comment: hi Jens, thank you for your help, your solution does work, it was a silly error I made, but if I want to add more OR clause for something else, where do I place it? For instance if I want to do something like OR user_location = "Munich", where would I place that little code? Thanks :)

Comment: @JamesSmith you can add it after ` account_ban = 0` or user_location = "Munich"

Comment: If I add line OR user_location = "Munich" what it ignores the account_type = 0 and account_ban = 0 and also displays the users who are not account_type = 0 and as well as those users that are banned :(

Comment: @JamesSmith That is the natural behavior od `OR` think you have to use `AND`

Comment: That is the problem, if I use `AND` rather then I will not get any result because to select location by user is optional to refine their search result. I guess the only solution could be the MySQL's `IF` conditions or the sub-query. Is it possible to get the location Munich from sub-query if Munich string was passed to the query or something like that?

Comment: @JamesSmith In this case you Need 2 queries.

Comment: What sql query logic would you use to do 2 of those queries? for example if user does provide a string for location attribute

Comment: @JamesSmith If i use it from a program i would build the query dynamicaly in the program. But i do not know how do you call the statement.

Comment: I am doing it in PHP, right now what I have is that if location variable is `true` then use the second query which has `AND Location =`. If location variable is empty then use the query which does not have `AND Location =` defined. If I do it like this then I will have to create like more than 5 different queries like this as user can also do things like get all users from certain town or country and so on

Comment: @JamesSmith Yes thats the way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot some brackets:

```
SELECT  firstname, lastname 
FROM users 
 WHERE (CONCAT(firstname,lastname) LIKE '%jb%'
         OR CONCAT(firstname,lastname) LIKE '%bj%') 
        AND account_type = 0 
        AND account_ban = 0;
```

This should solve your first problem.

Comment: I understood your answer quite late, just figured out what you meant. It did fix my original query. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "parenthesis" would have been the better word then "brackets" :)

Comment: yea i guess you're write etalon11 :P

Answer (score 1):

Use proper parenthesis will solve your problem. 
Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT  firstname, lastname 
FROM users 
 WHERE (CONCAT(firstname,lastname) LIKE '%jb%'
         OR CONCAT(firstname,lastname) LIKE '%bj%') 
        AND account_type = 0 
        AND account_ban = 0;
```